# C++ predicting majority of string array elegantly

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of 5 strings and I want to be able to compare the strings to each other to find out if there is a majority, and return that majority. So if:

```
a[0] = "dog";
a[1] = "dog";
a[2] = "dog";
a[3] = "dog";
a[4] = "cat";
```

I want to return "dog." In cases like 2 same, 2 same, and one, I want it to return "no majority". Is there a way to do this without a tremendous amount of if statements, in other words elegantly?

Comment: I don't think "predicting" is the right word.

Comment: Are there _always_ 5 strings or do you plan on this some day processing more than those 5?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a dictionary:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> historgram;
std::string most_popular;
unsigned int m = 0;
bool unique = false;

for (s : a)
{
    unsigned int & i = histogram[s];
    ++i; 
    if (i == m) { unique = false; }
    else if (i > m) { unique = true; m = i; most_popular = s; }
}

return unique ? most_popular : "no majority"'
```

Comment: what is the condition of the for loop?

Comment: @user3371287, It's a range-based for loop. There is no explicit condition.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in a hash table where the key is the word and the value the number of occurences. As you place them in the hash table check for the max count.

Not only you avoid the ifs, but (most important) it works whatever the length of the array is.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to have a `std::map<std::string, int>` which maps each string to its frequency in the array.

```
for (auto str : a) {
  frequencies[str]++;
}
```

You can then either search through the map afterwards for the highest frequency, or you can keep track of the maximum so far during the loop above.